# initializing OutlookEmail object gives Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)

Tags: c#, email, outlook

When I try to initialize object as:

```
   OutlookEMail email = new OutlookEMail(MailType);
```

in C# I get exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

Using Microsoft Office (outlook) 2007.
can someone help to resolve that?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a DLL, or it's the wrong format for your system.

Comment: Check out [the documentation for ApplicationClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationclass.aspx) it should help

Comment: The documentation (usually!) lists the DLL that the class is contained in.

Comment: https://github.com/phw198/OutlookGoogleCalendarSync/wiki/FAQs---COM-Errors

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same error, only it was when I ran the most simple line of code:

```
var outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

I tried various fixes proposed like running a "repair" and registering various components.  The fix was to change my project target from "Any CPU" to "x86".  I am running Windows 8.1 64-bit with 32-bit Office.