# Export to excel in TFS 2012, error code: TF400422

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 RC.

I'm working with TFS2012, and when I want to export a user story to excel I get the following dialog box error:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
Team Foundation Error
TF400422: Failed to open in Microsoft Excel: Error loading type library/Dll.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
```

I'm using `Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.`
Version: `14.0.6112.5000` (64-bit)

**Screenshot**

[image]

**What does the TF400422 code mean?**

I looked in [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337645%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which has a list of error code meanings, but the code: TF400422 isn't there.  Perhaps this relates to [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469497/initializing-outlookemail-object-gives-exception-from-hresult-0x80029c4a-type) issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm sorry for the late answer but I was managed to avoid this error by connecting to TFS from Excel using TEAM tab. Then I created new list using TFS Query and it works pretty good

Comment: What is TEAM tab?

** Edit ** The team tab in Excel

Answer (score 7):

Last I checked the TFS addin didn't work with 64bit of office.

It may have changed since the 2010 version, but it wouldn't surprise me if it was still the case.

Reference: First comment on this blog
http://geekswithblogs.net/blomqvist/archive/2010/10/25/integration-with-office-from-team-explorer-stopped-workingndashand-how-to.aspx

Comment: **2022** Note to Googlers: whilst probably a fine answer at the time, Excel x64 supports TFS add-in as at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 2):

The fix for this turns out to be simple - see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dau-blog/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application.aspx) for details.

From the registry, when you see two keys under:

```
HKCR\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\
```

delete the highest one. In my case this was 1.8, but it will depend on your version of Excel/Office (the artical describes deleting 1.7). This problem does seem to return after some time (maybe after patches), so you may have to re-apply this fix unfortunately.

Comment: I've only got one entry there, yet still had the problem described in the question...