# TFS 2012 error TF400422 when exporting to Excel

Tags: tfs, export-to-excel

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 (v11.0.060610.01 Update 3) and I also have Office Professional Plus 2010 installed in a Windows 7 Enterprise (with SP1) 64-bit operating system.

Since some weeks ago everytime I try to export in the result of a Work Items' query (through "Open Query in Microsoft Excel" option) I get:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Team Foundation Error

TF400422: Failed to open in Microsoft Excel: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

---

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

I already tried to repair and reinstall "Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office". The solution proposed in [Export to excel in TFS 2012, error code: TF400422](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551541/export-to-excel-in-tfs-2012-error-code-tf400422) does not work for me.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because TFS 2012/2013 don't work with 64-bit version of Office